# could anyone tell me the meaning of "because it was his voice" in the following excerpt?

Tags: meaning

- "In the 1990s, the avatar was named Johnny Miller, and he would shamelessly brag about Trump’s wealth and sexual conquests, in a voice that was uncannily like the Boss’s—because it *was* his voice."

Does this mean that Trump's voice is uncanny? I dont know what "his" refers to.

Comment: It means it was actually Trump's voice.

Comment: I guess im being dumb in here. lol. thanks